# Chrome extension No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header after 20 hours

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, cors

I use `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` to talk to some internal API.
Everything is perfect for the first 20 hours, I can call the API and get what I need.

After ~20 hours my extension stopped working and I get:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://MY_API' is therefore not allowed access.

I know that `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` will renew expired tokens and I can see that at `chrome://identity-internals/`, my code gets a new access token but cannot send the request.

If I uninstall / install extension again then it's working again.

Manifest contains:

```
"permissions": [ "tabs", "activeTab", "cookies", "identity", "<all_urls>" ]
```

What happens when I re-install my extension that makes the bug go away?

background.js:

```
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: true}, function(token) {

        gapi.auth.setToken({'access_token': token});

        // Load the storage API.
        gapi.client.load(API_ROOT + DISCOVERY_PATH,
            VERSION, function() {
          // Initialize GAPI's OAuth.
          gapi.auth.init(function() {
            var request = "It's request to my API";

            // Not working after 20 hours
            request.execute(function(response) {
             // do something
            });

          });
        });
      })
```

Also tried to call "chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken" but extension stopped working in 20 hours.

Comment: This requires one more important clarification. Where do you see this error? Is it in a content script? Because it's very strange that your API URL is the _origin_. Please include the code (masking out the URL) that triggers this error.

Comment: I updated my 1st post

Comment: Why.. Why are you using GAPI of all things to access your API?

Comment: That was example of this API usage. Sorry, I'm very new in that and it's my first experience with auth 2 / gapi / chrome extension.
Do I need to use another way to access my API (I got example with gapi load)'

Answer (score 0):

on server "https://MY_API" set this settings:

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

in .htaccess or httpd.conf (if server is httpd/apache)

Comment: That's making a (big) assumption that the API is controlled by the extension developer. That's rarely the case.

Comment: I cannot make such changes. I don't control that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you uninstall/reinstall the extension, its internal state is completely wiped; this makes your code get a completely fresh token, not refresh a previously-obtained one.

As for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header - this is a *server-side* response header, and we can only guess why this changes for some random 3rd-party API (that you didn't even name). A reasonable guess is that you're hitting some rate-limiting or quota, though it's very strange to use CORS for that.

This *particular* error can be brushed aside permanently by [requesting cross-origin permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#requesting-permission), which makes Chrome ignore CORS for requests from the extension (including content scripts). However, you should double-check usage terms of the API, if any.

Comment: Thank you. I cannot share this API name with you. It's something that our company owns. I have the following permissions: 
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "cookies",
    "identity",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
How can I get completely fresh token w/o reinstall? any way to do that?

Comment: If it's your own API, you should consider this a bug and investigate.

Comment: Okay, that's extremely interesting. If you have `"<all_urls>"` in permissions, no request from your extension can trigger this. So this means that `chrome.identity` API itself is not subject to cross-origin permissions. That's.. Strange. Possibly a bug in Chrome.

Comment: How can I simulate re-install in code w/o actual re-install? I tried remove token from cash but have the same problem.

Comment: You could try `chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken`. If you tried that already, can you add that to the question? I already updated it with your manifest.

Comment: Thank you. I added chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken, installed my extension and (obviously) it's working now. Will see tomorrow will it fail or not.